# which string i pass i did not Get data from url?

Tags: ios, json, parsing

So I have data data in this format:

`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

`<string>{"Records":[{"id":26,"date":"05/04/2014","name":"A Summary of the US Dietary Guidelines"},{"id":27,"date":"05/04/2014","name":"Accompaniments"}]}</string>`

If this is the format of data that I have, what should I be passing?

Code below:

```
  NSString *Webservice_url = self.texturl.text;
NSLog(@"URL %@",Webservice_url);

// Create NSURL from string.
NSURL *Final_Url = [NSURL URLWithString:Webservice_url];

// Get NSData from Final_Url
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: Final_Url];

//parse out the json data
NSError* error;


// Use NSJSONSerialization class method. which converts NSData to Foundation object.
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// Create Array
NSArray* Response_array = [json objectForKey:@"Records"];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", Response_array);

self.arr1 = [Response_array valueForKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@" %@",self.arr1);
```

Comment: What is that mix of XML & JSON?

Comment: i also know data is xml format But i want to pass in json format? is it possible?

which data i pass?